# Views PHP: Getting "Available Variables"

Tags: views

I am using Views PHP and having problem in doing a very basic thing.

In my view I added a field which I have to "Exclude from display" and show it only when there is a specific content type being called on Page.

So I used `Views PHP`, which checks the content type. The only problem is that I don't know how to output this field.

I used

```
$row -> myfield_name;
```

but that doesn't work.

So basically, I just need to use "Available Variables". But the `$row->myfield_name` doesn't work.

I can't use the following as this gives raw field.  I only want to use how this is intercepted in my view and how my view shows it. This is because this field is a video and my view is formatting it with JWplayer and hence calling it will call it as JWPlayer.

```
$value-> _field_data["body"] ["entity"] -> myfield_name ["und"][0]["value"];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables (or field) that you need to use as *Available Variables* must be **before** the *Views PHP* variable. Besides that install [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module and use `kpr($row)` or `kpr($view)` or `kpr($data)` to get the available properties of these variables.
Also in "Output" section you can use `var_dump` or `print_r` to print available variables.